# Remove element if equal to in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, element

I am trying to remove an element in jquery if the contents are equal to a variable set in jquery. In this example I am trying to remove .sub3 as the contents are equal to the variable set.

```
<div class="sub1">
    <a href="/large.jpg" class="group1 cboxElement">
    <img border="0" alt="" src="/thumb.jpg">
    </a>
</div>

<div class="sub2">
    <a href="/029-large.jpg" class="group1 cboxElement">
    <img border="0" alt="" src="/029-thumb.jpg">
    </a>
</div>

<div class="sub3">
    <a href="" class="group1 cboxElement"></a>
</div>
```

The Jquery I have come up with just removes the whole element regardless

```
var nopic = <a class="group1 cboxElement" href=""></a>;

if($.trim($(".sub1").text()) == nopic) {
$(".sub1").remove();
}

if($.trim($(".sub2").text()) == nopic) {
$(".sub2").remove();
}

if($.trim($(".sub3").text()) == nopic) {
$(".sub3").remove();
}
```

Thanks for any pointers!

Comment: You need to put quotes around <a class="group1 cboxElement" href=""></a> when declaring nopic. Makes sure you use single quotes though, or escape the other " in the line.

Comment: What do you mean "just removes the whole element regardless" ? Do you mean all divs get removed ? Also, I assume the content of the nopic variable is in a string (with quotes), right ? Is there a simpler way to decide that sub3 must be removed (the content of the a's href ? the fact that there is an image inside ?). Also, don't you want to compare the result of html() rather than test() ?

Comment: @Nik: In spite of all the answers, do not do this with string comparison. Browsers render HTML differently. It won't necessarily be identical to the HTML that came from the server. Use selectors and/or DOM traversal methods to see if the nested element exists. http://jsfiddle.net/Rfvuf/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One line, simple case that works on all empty links:

`$('div[class^="sub"] a.group1.cboxElement[href=""]').parent('div').remove()`

Comment: This would work, but may not be specific enough. There could be other `<a>` elements on the page with an empty `href`. Hard to say though. Certainly better than trying to do this by comparing HTML strings.

Comment: You were given specific classes and element structure. The targeted elements have a `class` attribute starting with `sub`, and should be removed if they have a child `a` element that has the classes `group1 cboxElement` and if the `a` does not have a nested `img` element. Plenty there to work with. Still, like I said, it may work for OP, and it is certainly better than the string comparison approach.

Answer (score 2):

If your intent is to just remove the inner div that does not contain an image the following will suffice:

```
$('div[class^="sub"]').filter(':not(:has(img))').remove();
```

Comment: This removes all divs on the page that do not have an image.

Comment: @RightSaidFred Code now updated to use attribute starts with selector. I was aware that it would remove all divs, however there wasn't a lot on the snippet to create a more targeted selector.

Comment: +1 After deleting mine, this is the only reasonable answer left.

Answer (score 0):

You should use html()

```
var nopic = '<a class="group1 cboxElement" href=""></a>';

if($.trim($(".sub3").html()) == nopic) {
    $(".sub3").remove();
}
```

Comment: OP should not do HTML string comparison to accomplish this. Different browsers render HTML differently.

Answer (score 0):

`.text()` returns the text content of a node, not its HTML. You want `.html()` instead.

e.g.

Hello

```
$('#blah').text() -> Hello
$('#blah').html() -> <a href="somewhere">Hello</a>
```

Comment: OP should not do HTML string comparison to accomplish this. Different browsers render HTML differently.

Answer (score 0):

You've got three problems I can see:

1. syntax errors for your assignment of the `nopic` variable. You need quotes around the value you're assigning to it.
2. Given your current html, your `.subX` elements don't have any text inside them. They have html. So you should be using the `.html()` method rather than `.text()`.
3. Even once you fix the issue I described in #1, it still won't work because the value of nopic won't be equal to the `<a>` tag in `.sub3` (which I assume is what you're using to test). That's because the `href` and `class` attributes are reversed.

Here's the working JS, as well as [a live example](http://jsfiddle.net/nEHTp/):

```
var nopic = '<a href="" class="group1 cboxElement"></a>';

if($.trim($(".sub1").html()) == nopic) {
        $(".sub1").remove();
}

if($.trim($(".sub2").html()) == nopic) {
    $(".sub2").remove();
}

if($.trim($(".sub3").html()) == nopic) {
    $(".sub3").remove();
}
```

Comment: OP should not do HTML string comparison to accomplish this. Different browsers render HTML differently.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be going about this backwards. What you are trying to do is remove a `div` if it contains that link tag. It would probably be easier to find the `a` you're looking for and remove it's parent.

```
$('a.group1.cboxElement').parents('div[class^="sub"]').remove();
```

Comment: This removes all the parents of all the `a.group1.cboxElement` elements. Clearly not what is wanted.

Comment: How is that clearly not intended? Just because he didn't phrase the question that way doesn't mean that isn't ultimately what he's trying to achieve.

Comment: How did this get an up vote? It is *clear* because in the question OP is locating the element whose content matches the string, and then removing only that element. Yours matches all the `a.group1.cboxElement` elements, and removes all their parents.

Comment: It won't remove the body element because `.parents('div')` stops at the first parent this is a `div`. Again, just because he thought about solving the problem the way he described it, doesn't mean it's the only way or even the right way. This is a different approach based on how I read what he was trying to achieve. It is a perfectly valid solution and frankly I'm not sure why you're so hell bent on hassling me about it.

Comment: Yes, I just updated my comment because you have the filter, but it still removes all the `.sub` elements, and any potential `<div>` ancestors. If that was the intent, why would OP be doing the comparisons that distinguish the different `.sub` elements? Clearly only the ones that pass the `if` statement are to be removed. I'm not hassling you. I'm correcting your wrong answer.